# Is there any English word for two people having the same character/nature but they do not look alike?

Tags: single-word-requests

They don't look alike (so aren't physical "twins") but their nature is similar, may I know words for that...?

Comment: Can you edit to give more details? Is there such a term in your native language?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **kindred spirits**.

Soul mates works too, but often has the implication that the people concerned are (potentially) romantically involved with one another.

(Added) Another term to use would be to say that the people concerned are **on the same wavelength**.

Answer (score 1):

> They don't look alike, but they are **soul mates**.

**soul mate**

> 1: a person who is perfectly suited to another in temperament
>
> 2: a
> person who strongly resembles another in attitudes or beliefs
> *ideological soul mates* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soul%20mate)